# Maven: Can i have resources copied in WEB-INF and also in some other directory?

Tags: maven

I want some resources to be copied in 2 different directories. How can i specify this in pom?

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy-resources</id>
      <!-- here the phase you need -->
      <phase>validate</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>
          ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/lib
        </outputDirectory>
        <resources>          
          <resource>
            <directory>${SOME_LIB}</directory>
          </resource>
        </resources>              
      </configuration>                      
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Do you mean that one resource `a.txt` should go to `target/folderA/lib/` and another resource `b.png` to `target/folderB/lib/`? Or should both/all resources go to two places?

Comment: all resources to two locations...                                                           target1/folderA/lib as well as target2/folderB/lib

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `<resources/>` tag inside the `<build/>` block instead.

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/txt</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>*.txt</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/png</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>*.png</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${SOME_LIB}</directory>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/lib</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>*.dll</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

This way you can sort different files to different targets paths.

---

For your exact problem this would work:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${SOME_LIB}</directory>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/lib</targetPath>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${SOME_LIB}</directory>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF</targetPath>
    </resources>
</build>
```

The resources will be copied to BOTH target directories, just as you want.

Comment: But can i have the same resources to be doubled in different targets?

Comment: @Aditya Yes you can! See my second example.

Comment: @Aditya Good. Now accept the answer and maybe give it an up-vote. I will up-vote your question after that.

Answer (score 0):

outputDirectories is a java.io.File type, so based on the plugin, you would have to configure 2 executions.

Pity it wasn't designed to handle

```
<outputDirectories>
    <outputDirectory>1</outputDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>2</outputDirectory>
</outputDirectories>
```

Comment: I tried giving two executions but only the files are reflected only in the last location.